# WPF - Doesn't find all usercontrols in other assembly in XAML

Tags: wpf, user-controls, reference

I have this other assembly which has a folder with 10 UserControls and I reference the assembly in XAML so I can use them.

```
xmlns:usercontrols="clr-namespace:Company.Project.OtherAssembly.UserControls;assembly=Company.Project.OtherAssembly"
```

However, when I try to use the UserControls with `<usercontrols:someUserControl />` it only finds 4 of the 10 UserControls.

I have no idea why, they all have the same namespace. It even finds a public class within a UserControl but not the actual UserControl.

Any help on this matter is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean that you do not see them in the IntelliSense ? Or it does not compile ?

This may be just that XAML editor in your VS does not treat some of your user controls well. IntelliSense in WPF is sometimes hard to understand.

Comment: I don't see them in IntelliSense. I'll try and see what happens if I try adding something it doesn't find and compile.

Comment: I could just write them even if they did not show up and it would compile. Thanks.

Comment: I also ran into this issue. What I did is I reloaded the xaml project.

Answer (score 0):

IntelliSense for XAML relies on built assemblies. Try rebuilding the project with the controls.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't see the UserControls in Intellisense, try to restart Visual Studio or rebuild the Solution.

Answer (score 0):

When I ran into the same problem this is what worked for me:
Make sure that all those controls have parameter-less public constructors.